# Simple SparkR dapply example not working

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I'm trying to write a really simple SparkR program that uses a `dapply` to transform a line. However, I have trouble running it:

```
lines <- read.text("/path/to/file.txt")

resultingSchema <- structType(structField("line", "string"))

linesmapped <- dapply(lines, function(line) {
    y <- list()
    y[[1]] <- paste(line[[1]], "1", sep = ":")    
}, resultingSchema)

head(linesmapped)
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Error in split.default(output, seq(nrow(output))) :
  group length is 0 but data length > 0
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRunner.compute(RRunner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.r.MapPartitionsRWrapper.apply(MapPartitionsRWrapper.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.r.MapPartitionsRWrapper.apply(MapPartitionsRWrapper.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$6.apply(objects.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$6.apply(objects.scala:175)
```

Answer (score 4):

I had made too many elementary mistakes. I hope this is useful to somebody else (since SparkR documentation is very sparse at the moment):

```
lines <- read.text("/path/to/file.txt")
resultingSchema <- structType(structField("value", "string"))

ldf <- dapply(lines, function(x) {    
    x <- transform(x, value=paste(value, "$", sep=""))
}, resultingSchema)

head(collect(ldf))
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic thing with dapply is to remember that the function within dapply expect a dataframe and output will also be a dataframe.

So think about the partition getting passed to dapply function as a native R dataframe and apply functions accordingly.